# Read-only file system when attempting mkdir /root/.local/share on Mac with Putty

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am trying to start Bitnami AWS with Putty in mac, but when i start Auth in SSH with both Catalina and Big Sur i get this error:

```
(putty: 3637): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/Users/daniele/.local/share/recently-used.xbel ', but failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install the folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share
```

I get this error:

```
mkdir: /root/.local/share: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, we should create the folder at the following path:

```
/Users/daniele/.local/share/
```

And not:

```
/root/.local/share
```

Therefore, the correct command is:

```
mkdir -p /Users/Daniele/.local/share
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Require the result in command: `csrutil status`
2. If result is enabled, you need to restart machine and press `command + R`, open the terminal in the recovery, so input `csrutil diabled`.
3. Restart, and check the status: `csrutil status`.

Here are two methods:

1. you are root.

   sudo mount -uw /
   so, you could mkdir or touch new file.
2. If you still can't read or write any, you maybe try this:

   cd ~ # cd home directory
   sudo vim /etc/synthetic.conf # create new file if this doesn't exist

In the conf files, add new line

```
data /User/xx/data # Notice: the space between this two strings is tab
```

Restart, and you will find a link named `/data` in the root.